# SFINAE for class member overload methods

Tags: c++, templates, member, sfinae, enable-if

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct UseMap;
struct NoMap;

template<typename MapType = NoMap>
class MyClass
{
public:

  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<MapType, NoMap>::value, bool>::type
  handleEvent(int someVal)
  {
    return doSomething();
  }

  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<MapType, UseMap>::value, bool>::type
  handleEvent(int someVal)
  {
    return doSomethingDifferent();
  }

  bool doSomething() {};
  bool doSomethingDifferent() {};
};

int main() {
  MyClass obj1();
  MyClass<UseMap> obj2();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to compile only one `handleEvent` method, depending on the provided template class type?
With the example above the compiler gives:

```
prog.cpp:18:3: error: 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<MapType, UseMap>::value, bool>::type MyClass<MapType>::handleEvent(int)' cannot be overloaded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to make the overloaded functions template.

```
template<typename T = MapType,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, NoMap>::value>::type *& = nullptr>
bool
handleEvent(int someVal)
{
  return doSomething();
}

template<typename T = MapType,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, UseMap>::value>::type *& = nullptr>
bool
handleEvent(int someVal)
{
  return doSomethingDifferent();
}
```

This passes compile. (clang-600.0.54 with `-std=c++11`)

Answer (score 1):

Complement to findall's answer : you can also inherit from an easily specializable base class.

```
struct UseMap;
struct NoMap;

template<typename>
class MyClass;

namespace detail {
  // Container for the handleEvent() function
  template<typename>
  struct MyClassHandler;
}

// Enter CRTP !
template<typename MapType = NoMap>
class MyClass : detail::MyClassHandler<MyClass<MapType>>
{
    friend class detail::MyClassHandler<MyClass<MapType>>;
public:
  using detail::MyClassHandler<MyClass<MapType>>::handleEvent;

  bool doSomething() {};
  bool doSomethingDifferent() {};
};

// Actual specializations now that the full definition of MyClass is in scope
namespace detail {
  template<>
  struct MyClassHandler<MyClass<NoMap>> {
    bool handleEvent(int someVal)
    {
      return static_cast<MyClass<NoMap>*>(this)->doSomething();
    }
  };

  template<>
  struct MyClassHandler<MyClass<UseMap>> {
    bool handleEvent(int someVal)
    {
      return static_cast<MyClass<UseMap>*>(this)->doSomethingDifferent();
    }
  };
}
```

I feel like I overcomplicated the declaration order a bit, double-check welcome :)